# Grails 3.3.5 with SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, grails, keystore

I have _client-cert.pem and client-key.pem and ca.pem files which I am trying to add to my grails project.

I used following commands :

Convert client keys/certificate files to PKCS#12 before creating a keystore

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem \ 
-name “mysqlclient” -passout pass:mypassword -out client-keystore.p12
```

2. Create a Java Keystore using the client-keystore.p12 file

   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client-keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 \ 
   -srcstorepass mypassword -destkeystore keystore -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass mypassword

Then Modified my application.yml file with that path :

```
enabled: true
key-store: /..../proxreg
key-store-password:kjsfghsfjlhgl
keyStoreType: pkcs12
keyAlias: tomcat
```

I was wondering if I am missing any step or what am I doing wrong. I am getting access denied error but when I try to connect thro mysql wokbench it works

Comment: Is this the _exact_ indenting you are using for the `application.yml`?  If so, the problem is most likely there.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a self-signed certificate using the [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) command-line utility.

We can use openssl's req command to create a self-signed certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Above will prompt you to supply metadata about the certificate, such as Country, Organization, etc. Moreover, it will ask you to provide a PEM pass phrase. Enter a random password and keep it safe; we will need in the next step.

Now you have you self-signed certificate. *Unfortunately Grails (and Spring Boot) doesn’t support the PEM format directly.* Instead, we need to use the PKCS12 format for our keys. Fortunately, there is another openssl command to make the conversion:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out keystore.p12 -name tomcat -caname root
```

Update grails-app/conf/application.yml with the following lines:

```
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
        keyStore: /certificates/keystore.p12
        keyStorePassword: secret
    #    keyAlias: tomcat
```

Above all worked fine with me. for more information please refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwnEmLx2LRs) and [this](http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/deployment/2017/06/28/running-grails-with-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate.html)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have to use the certificates which are generated by the sys admin and those are creating a problem

Comment: @SnehalP Which certificates do you have `.pem` file or `.p12` file. You can use `.p12` file directly with grails (I'm using same)

Comment: I have .pem and I converted them to .p12 as grails can not use .pem